# hidden field can't show in jsp

Tags: jsp

```
    function display(){


        document.getElementById(code).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(sname).style.visibility = 'visible';
       document.getElementById(ss).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }


           <input type="submit" value="Add Subject" name="addition" onclick="return display()">
    </form>
    <div id="F2" hidden="hidden">
        <form id="hiddenform" name="Assign" method="post" width="960" border="0" action="NewServlet" >
        <table align="center" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" id="t" >
                    <tr><td>
                        </td><td><input type="hidden" type="text" name="code" placeholder="Enter subject code"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="hidden" type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Enter subject name"></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="hidden" type="submit"  value="ADD SUBJECT" name="ss"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

this can't show the hidden fields can any one help me I like show two text fiels code,sname and ss button

Comment: your code is incomplete where this `</form>` tag start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i give solution to your problem i have marked something in your code as below :
1. You code is incomplete there is no start tag for `</form>` at line two (html code).
2. You have used `document.getElementById(code)` even though you have not given `id` to your input element.

A hidden input field is supposed to remain hidden. You may use css to hide and show your TextBox by setting `style="display:none;"` property.

**Solution :**
Remove `type="hidden"` from the input element. From your code it seems that you only want your div `<div id="F2">`  which contain form `<form id="hiddenform"` inside, to show or hide on button click.

For this just need one line in your JavaScript line, no need to hide each element.

```
document.getElementById("F2").style.display = 'block';
```

Your Complete Code here :

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Subject" name="addition" onclick="return display()">
</form>
<div id="F2" style="display:none;">
    <form id="hiddenform" name="Assign" method="post" width="960" border="0" action="NewServlet" >
    <table align="center" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" id="t" >
      <tr><td></td>
          <td><input type="text"  name="code"  placeholder="Enter subject code"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="sname"  placeholder="Enter subject name"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td><input  type="submit" value="ADD SUBJECT" name="ss"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function display(){
     document.getElementById("F2").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: function display(){
     document.getElementById("F2").style.display = 'block';
} is not work but function called what error in this line

Comment: i need some suggestion ,if i click that button it will shown but once again if i chick that text field will appear once again what can i do

Comment: it will not appear once again till it is display. it will show when it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `<input type="hidden" type="text"`.

Inputs can have `type="hidden"` or `type="text"`, but not both.

If you want to hide a text field you should use `style="display_none"`.

In your case, you should stick to `type="text"`.

Comment: its k that field are hide but how to display using function

Comment: i need some suggestion ,if i click that button it will shown but once again if i chick that text field will appear once again what can i do

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just faced the same issue myself...and none of these work that well unless your generic brain is copying code from www3 schools. Ajax is also better to use than plain js in a script file.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">. 
</script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   //once the addition button is clicked on
   $(".addition").click(function() {
     //this will show everything in F2
     $(".F2").show();
     //you can also move style="display:none" around to control what you 
       want to hide within the form
     //this is how you can hide individual elements on your form as well
     $(".submit").hide()
   
}
</script>
```

This style="display:none" will hide the whole table, or can be used to hide different elements...up in your  file once clicked on add button it will show whatever you want to show, called by class.

```
       <input type="submit" value="Add Subject" class="addition" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="F2" style="display:none">
    <form name="Assign" method="post" width="960" border="0" action="NewServlet" >
    <table align="center" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" id="t" >
                <tr><td>
                    </td><td><input class="inputCode" type="text" name="code" placeholder="Enter subject code"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input class="inputName" type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Enter subject name"></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input class="submit" type="submit"  value="ADD SUBJECT" name="ss"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```